# MySQL Entity Framework Migrations

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, code-first

we tried to implement migrations for our code first EF5 MySQL project.  But when we run the update-database command in the package manager, we get a weird error:

Anyone any idea why??

> System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifest instance. ---> System.ArgumentException: Could not determine storage version; a valid storage connection or a version hint is required.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlVersionUtils.GetSqlVersion(String versionHint)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderManifest..ctor(String manifestToken)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifest(String versionHint)
>      at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifest(String manifestToken)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifest(String manifestToken)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Sql.SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator.Generate(IEnumerable`1 migrationOperations, String providerManifestToken)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, XDocument targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()

Comment: Can you please place your dbcontext class here as well as your web.config file so we can take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the  MySql.Data.MySqlClient API instead of System.Data.SqlClient. 
The DLL is located here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient.html